# Extjs Treeview: How do you remove dotted line between nodes

Tags: extjs, treeview, treepanel

I’m working on a Extjs Treeview. I can’t seem to figure out of to remove the dotted lines between the nodes. I know it has to be a stylesheet issue but I can not figured out the correct property. Please advise

Comment: Which version of ExtJs are you using? Which toolkit (modern or classic), may you provide some code?

Comment: And which theme are you using, classic, crips.. material.. ?